How to use Power Automate to copy files in SharePoint that match a certain pattern
I have files (abc 1000.xlsx, def 1001.xlsx, ghj 1002.xlsx, etc...) in source_folder. I want to copy each of these file to the corresponding '1000', '1001', '1002', etc... folder in dest_folder'.
How can I accomplish this using Power Automate Manually Trigger A Flow.
Results are folder '1000' will contain abc 1000.xlsx, folder '1001' will contain def 1001.xlsx and so on.

I would do it with a list of folder names. Next, use List Files to get all files from the sharepoint server. Then for each folder, filter the files list where "filename contains current item". Move all files in this list to the "current item" (it will be the folder name).
Here's a rough structure:


sorry but i don't see any of these steps possible in SharePoint

that's not sharepoint. you need to implement this solution on a power-automate flow and connect with the relevant sharepoint server using right credentials.

off course, How to use Power Automate to copy files in SharePoint that match certain pattern
